# error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am new to C# and I am having a hard time solving an error. When I log in, I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

I know this means the table does not exist, but how do I correct it? My Database contains 4 tables and the table I am referring to is the third table in the database(I don't know if this will help). Please tell me if you need more information. I think the problem is with the loop somewhere, because I get no syntax errors.

**My login code in my web user control(just for background information)**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
       <% if (Session["Patient"] == "Logged In")
        { %> 
                <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" Text="Logout" onclick="Logout_Click" />&nbsp;<br /><br />
                <a>Continue to:</a> &nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="homepage" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/home.aspx">Home page</asp:LinkButton>|
                <asp:LinkButton ID="book_appointment" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/appointments.aspx">Book an Appointment</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Visible="false">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
        <% }
            else
        { %>
        <br />
                <a>Username: 
                <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /><br />
                Password: 
                <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox> </a><br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="Login_Click" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="linkRegister" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/register.aspx">Register</asp:LinkButton><br /><br />
                <a><asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></a><br /><br />
        <% } %>
```

**This is the code behind on my login control:**

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cQuery record = new cQuery(); //declare instance
    record.Sqlstring = "SELECT username, password FROM dbo.patient_details"; //what to get from database -- sql query
    DataSet data = record.SelectStatement(); //put info into dataset

    DataTable table = data.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if (row[0].ToString() == username.Text)
        {
            if (row[1].ToString() == password.Text)
            {
                Session["Patient"] = row[0];
                Response.Redirect("myaccount.aspx");
                return;
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: That error implies that you are using something that is null, or unistantiated... what line is it breaking on?

Comment: I marked you down, not sure if you are experienced enough to ask a better question. You didn't ask a question as much as just post some code and expect someone to fix it, what line number is throwing error?

Answer (score 2):

> I know this means the table does not exist

No, it doesn't.  if the table did not exist yo would get a SQL error.

What it means (assuming it's occurring in the method you posted, which you haven't confirmed) is that one of the variables below is null:

```
row[0]
row[1]
username
password
```

Which I doubt unless you have a record with a `null` password, or the `username` and `password` controls are created dynamically.  Look at the stack trace of the exception and you should be able to pinpoint *where* the error occurs.